# IBM MQ - MDB Redelivery Delay configuration

Tags: jms, websphere, ibm-mq, message-driven-bean, tomee-7

I am trying to consume message from WebSphere MQ using  MDB and configured in ejb-jar.xml . am using below mentioned tech stack. I need to add redelivery delay option in my MDB activation config.

**Reference**
http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-webspheremq.html

**Tech stack**

```
1. TomEE 7.0.3 
2. Java EE 7 
3. JMS 2.0 
4. IBM MQ 8.0
```

**How to Configure blockedRetryTimeout in IBM MQ resource adapter ?**

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1407_titheridge/1407_titheridge.html

Comment: It does not appear that initialRedeliveryDelay is a valid setting for IBM MQ.

Comment: what is the valid RedeliveryDelay for IBM MQ ?

Comment: Dont think this is supported in MQ JMS. Refer this : http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=73120&sid=10288a46ba097ca77eb5c91c72e7f22c

Comment: I think page talks about message delivery delay. I need re delivery message delay

Comment: Look at last message in the thread. "The Delivery Delay that is in JMS 2.0/MQ 8.0 is different than the ability to set some type of redelivery delay for a backed out message. The redelivery delay that is described in that first link looks like something that is available in the WebLogic JMS provider, but not with the MQ JMS provider. At least as far as I know. -- [tczielke](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/profile.php?mode=viewprofile&u=27382)"

Comment: Does JMS or JCA api has redelivery delay option to do this ?

Comment: I have modified my query . Can anybody look at my query and help me on this ?

Comment: The `blockedRetryTimeout` is a setting available in Webspher Application Server V8.x's default messaging provider, this is noted at the top of the section that references it "Using the default messaging provider".  If you go down further to the section "Using the WebSphere MQ messaging provider" where it discussing the IBM MQ product you will see this setting is not available.

Comment: I am using TomEE and IBM Resource Adapter Jar. please guide me how to set up the blockedRetryTimeout via resource adapter jar.

Comment: Not sure how to say this any more clear. The IBM MQ product (formerly known as Websphere MQ, formerly known as MQSeries) does NOT support `blockedRetryTimeout`.  The `blockedRetryTimeout` seting is a setting in the Websphere Application Servers V8.x's default messaging provider which is not IBM MQ.  You are using the IBM MQ Resource Adapter, which is part of IBM MQ which does not support blockedRetryTimeout.